# How scale an SVG to cater for dynamic content inside it

Tags: css, svg, jinja2

Currently we're using jinja templating to create dynamic content in an svg file. The svg file contains jinja variables which are updating consistantly from the db. As the digits in the svg grow, we need the graphic to expand. In css this would be a simple padding solution, however it seems that one can't add padding in an svg.

Here's a screenshot of what's happening currently: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hu8wb.png

Here is the first circle within the svg that we are dynamically populating

```
<g id="Group-2-Copy-7" transform="translate(0.000000, 15.000000)">
  <circle id="Oval-2" fill="#4A4A4A" fill-rule="nonzero" cx="69" cy="69" r="69"></circle>
  <text id="Community-Name-Copy-2" font-family="Montserrat-SemiBold, Montserrat" font-size="70" font-weight="500" line-spacing="80" fill="#FFFFFF">
                        <tspan x="21.5" y="91">{{ community.events|count }}</tspan>
                    </text>
  <text id="Community-Name-Copy-4" font-family="Montserrat-Regular, Montserrat" font-size="10" font-weight="normal" line-spacing="12" fill="#FFFFFF">
                        <tspan x="45" y="110">EVENTS</tspan>
                    </text>
</g>
```

Ideally we'd like the circle to grow in this instance as the digit grows from the `{{ community.events|count }}` variable.

Comment: set the r value of the circle to {{ community.events|count }}

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson - that's a good point, will try that out.